# Store access tokens related to user accounts

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, architecture, authorization, access-token

what is the best approach to store access tokens related to users?
Right now I’m using react native and firebase for user authorization. What I want now is a autherization to a service like Strava or something like that where I get a access token. This token should be linked and somehow stored (where and how?) in relation to a specific user. Means that if this user logs out and back in this access token should be consistent. The same if this user is logging in at another device or something like this.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you would need a database, like MySQL or MongoDB which will store the access and refresh tokens from Strava and a userId. Once the user logs in to your app, you can look up the access token, regardless of the device you're on. Of course this would need to be secure - you should first make sure that the user authenticates and only then get the Strava access token from the database.